# MongoDB. Which data model I should choose for my project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

Started to learn MongoDB + node.js.
For practice I want to create webapp which collect data and draw infographic. But I have very big problem with choosing data model for MongoDB base.

How it works now, but I think it's bad structure.

My service retrieving all data from API every hour and collecting it in collection "accounts".

**Main question: It's Ok to do this: Every experience value from every hour in special object "expStart" with unique key which generated by request time?**

Structure of one document from collection "accounts" :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54bd56cb699f4890160aacc9"),
"name" : "Shubiii",
"characters" : [ 
    {
        "online" : false,
        "rank" : 562,
        "dead" : false,
        "name" : "ShrupShurp",
        "league" : "hardcore",
        "level" : 93,
        "class" : "Ranger",
        "experience" : 2515197599,
        "expStat" : {
            "dd2015_1_19_19_9" : 122120,
            "dd2015_1_19_20_11" :45222
        }
    },
    {
        "online" : false,
        "rank" : 563,
        "dead" : false,
        "name" : "ShrupShurp2",
        "league" : "hardcore",
        "level" : 93,
        "class" : "Ranger",
        "experience" : 2515197599,
        "expStat" : {
            "dd2015_1_19_19_9" : 3122120,
            "dd2015_1_19_20_11" :21212
        }
    }
],
"challenges" : {
    "total" : 3
},
"twitch" : {
    "name" : ""
}
```

}

This is API data structure (http://www.pathofexile.com/developer/docs/api):

```
{
"total": 15000,
"entries": [
    {
        "online": false,
        "rank": 2,
        "dead": false,
        "character": {
            "name": "iamgodyi",
            "level": 100,
            "class": "Ranger",
            "experience": 4250334444
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "TW_James",
            "challenges": {
                "total": 0
            },
            "twitch": {
                "name": "destiny601"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "online": true,
        "rank": 3,
        "dead": false,
        "character": {
            "name": "xVisco",
            "level": 100,
            "class": "Templar",
            "experience": 4250334444
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "xVisco",
            "challenges": {
                "total": 0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54bd56cb699f4890160aacc9"),
  "name" : "Shubiii",
  "characters" : {
                   "online" : false,
                   "rank" : 562,
                   "dead" : false,
                   "name" : "ShrupShurp",
                   "league" : "hardcore",
                   "level" : 93,
                   "class" : "Ranger",
                   "experience" : 2515197599,
                   "expStat" : {
                                 "dd2015_1_19_19_9" : 122120,
                                 "dd2015_1_19_20_11" :45222
                               }
                  },
  "challenges" : {
                   "total" : 3
                 },
  "twitch" : {
               "name" : ""
             }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you decided to go for this model?

Comment: Yes  In my case if i want to retrieve values like level  etc then i retrieve easily

Comment: If you have nice idea then you will post here.

Comment: account can have more than 1 characters. "characters" shoold be array of objects.

Comment: @ketul and I can't use character name as key name for object cuz it can have any restricted characters

Comment: Why information do you want to get from the API data? That's how we should start designing the schema.

Comment: @wdberkeley I want have information about changing experience every hour of every character of every account